# Graphics not working properly on Ubuntu 17.10 with Radeon HD 5450

Tags: graphics, 17.10, radeon, amd-graphics

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 and my graphics seem to have gone out of whack.

I'm using a 10 year old Core 2 Duo with an AMD Radeon HD 5450 and 4GB of RAM.
I connect to my Viewsonic VA1912wb monitor via a DVI cable from my graphics card.

Until 17.04, I was using the open-source display drivers for the Radeon cards, and was able to get games like Civilization V (on Steam) to work well enough.

After upgrading to 17.10, though, I only see black where there should be 3d graphics on the screen. 2d Games like Mahjongg and Abe's Amazing Adventure work fine. Even the glxgears app shows me 3 gears rotating as expected. But Civilization V is now unplayable.

Here is what I have checked till now:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]

$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:25 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0200000-e021ffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff

$ apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-radeon 
xserver-xorg-video-radeon:
  Installed: 1:7.10.0-1
  Candidate: 1:7.10.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 1:7.10.0-1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ apt-cache policy xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu 
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu:
  Installed: 1.4.0-1
  Candidate: 1.4.0-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.4.0-1 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ xrandr --listproviders 
Providers: number : 0
```

I understand that the last command should have listed my Radeon drivers/card but it doesn't.

As you can see I have both the radeon and amdgpu drivers installed, though uninstalling either, makes no difference. I continue to see `configuration: driver=radeon` even if I uninstall `xserver-xorg-video-radeon`.

I have tried following the instructions at http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx however the extraction of the downloaded driver file using `xz` gives the error `File format not recognized`.

How do I check what is wrong with my graphics configuration? Is this related to Wayland being the default display server?

Comment: AMDGPU doesn't have any support for HD 5450. Why install it? Supported cards are listed here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx.

Comment: It was auto installed when I upgraded from 17.04. In any case, the Radeon driver is the one that is being used.

Comment: Actually, you are right, AMDGPU is preinstalled along with Radeon, I got a bit hasty, and meant AMDGPU-PRO that you've mentioned. I also have HD5450 installed on an old desktop with AMD's Athlon II. It just works in Ubuntu Mate 17.10, and I've not tried Gnome3.